# How to create a virtual file that is coupled to a program, e.g. to a `.gz` file via `gzip`?

Tags: linux, files

Given e.g. a gzipped textfile `file.txt.gz`, how to create a special file `file.txt` that on reading yields the (interactively) decompressed contents of the `.gz` file, and on writing a) re-`gzip`s the new content or b) denies write-access?

Comment: Is there something wrong with just using `zcat`?

Comment: @jordanm `gzip` was just an example, next time it could be `tar` or an entirely different program that (transparently) converts (one-way or two-way) between two data formats

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to achieve by doing this, perhaps there's a simpler solution for your problem without the need of these special files.

Comment: @DavidKohen In general? A transparent data conversion tool one output of which other programs can simply treat as files. I guess FUSE is the best choice here indeed

Comment: That's what pipes are made for, though this may be an interesting FUSE file system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Linux (or FreeBSD, NetBSD, MacOS X) [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) comes to mind, it already features some [Archive File Systems](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=ArchiveFileSystems), that you should have a look at.

If the FUSE-mounted virtual file system just passes through non-archive-files, this could be what you want.

Comment: Yes, FUSE sounds like it can do it, though I wonder if one can mount to a file instead of a directory containing a dummy file (if the example's archive contains only compressed data)

Comment: If you are talking about a few files, you may be able to do something like this with softlinks (so it'll be files and not directories) and FUSE, of you are talking many (100+) I think you need to go elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidKohen Good point. It would only be a couple of files, so an alias that mounts to a `mktemp` directory and softlinking would suffice indeed

Comment: As it doesn't seem completely unrelated, I'd like to point out that some filesystems (among them Btrfs, Reiser4 and ZFS) support (per-filesystem) [transparent compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Allocation_and_layout_policies)